# Listview with edittext issue when appear keybord

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

[image]

i am using custom listview with edit text

when i click on last edit text of listview and all full activity is scroll to up

but i want to scroll only listview when keyboard appear

[image]

my java code of custom listview

```
class CreateAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>  {
        String[] strItecode=null;
        String[] strItem;
        String[] strQuantity;
        Context context;

        int temp;
        CreateAdapter(Context context, String[] strItemcode, String[] strItem,
                String[] strQauntity) {
            super(context, R.layout.create_list_item, R.id.txtItemcode, strItemcode);
            this.context = context;
            this.strItecode = strItemcode;
            this.strItem = strItem;
            this.strQuantity = strQauntity;
           // text= new String[strItem.length];
        }
        private int editingPosition = 0;
        private TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher() {
                  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                      text[editingPosition] = s.toString();
                  }
                  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }
                  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }
              };

        public View getView( final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder = null;
            temp=position;
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (convertView == null) {

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = mInflater
                        .inflate(R.layout.create_list_item, parent, false);

                holder.txtItecode = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.txtItemcode);
                holder.txtItem = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.txtItem);
                holder.editQuantity = (EditText) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.editcreateQuantity);
                holder.editQuantity.setTag(position);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.editQuantity.removeTextChangedListener(watcher);
           if(text[temp].contentEquals("0"))
               holder.editQuantity.setText("");
           else
            holder.editQuantity.setText(text[temp]);

            holder.editQuantity.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {       
                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                  if(hasFocus) editingPosition = position;
                }
            });

            holder.editQuantity.addTextChangedListener(watcher);

            // The rest is good, just make sure to remove the call to setting the EditText's text at the end
            holder.txtItecode.setText(strItecode[position]);
            holder.txtItem.setText(strItem[position]);
          //  holder.editQuantity.setText(text[temp]);
            return convertView;


        }

        class ViewHolder {
            TextView txtItecode;
            TextView txtItem;
            EditText editQuantity;
        }
    }
```

My manifest code of this activity

```
  <activity android:name=".CreateChallan" android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:screenOrientation="portrait"

             android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
```

Please Help me how i can set scroll only listview not full activity when keyboard appear

Thanks In Advance

And i am realy sorry about my bad english

Comment: What do you mean by `all full activity is scroll to up`?

Comment: @Aniruddha show this pic [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/t6DFs.png)

Answer (score 0):

This might help.

**Use:** `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

If you change Layout structure like this:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/text_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
         //other view if you have any..

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

It will display full listview and overlap other views.